# Android Studio Classes Could be Instantiated

Tags: android

[content_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ii96.png)

[activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNMh1.png)

I was trying to following an online youtube android beginner class tutorial, but when I create a new blank activity, the 3 dot on the right top overflow menu does not show and this rendering problem happened. I've tried to change the API to 22, 21, 19 and also tried changing the style.xml method, both doesn't work for me. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific and put some code. It seems you don't added menu.xml including settings Menu item.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.derrick.ciatest.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>  
  
sorry, i'm new here. this is the menu.xml

Answer (score 0):

For Menu u have to override the below functions.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Even though menu is not available in preview,just test it in emulator or real device.It works perfectly.

Comment: this is included inside the mainactivity already by default when i created a new blank activity. any other solution?

Comment: We can get the menu when this coding is there in the Activity.Is it not available?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what is not available. I still can't get the menu out.

Comment: If you have the above coding in ur class then menu should be available.Did u run in emulator and saw?

Comment: i can't run my emulator, i can't seems to install the HXAM accelerator, i wonder is it cause of i'm using amd processor. But i do have those code in it, it's just the same.

Comment: Then how u run the projects?In real device?

Comment: yes, but if the rendering problem is not solved, it wouldn't affect the outcome of the app? If that so, i would face a layout trouble by not being able to view in android studio right?

Comment: U can run the project now right? just run it and see if menu are available.bcoz in preview it may not be visible.

Comment: Hey i just tryd it.Adding those coding in the MainActivity just displays the menu when running the project.Just give a try,

Comment: Alright, I will try running it with my device. The code is already in the main menu since it is created by default bro.

Comment: Ok try it.I will send the full coding if its not working.

Comment: I've tested with my phone, it works perfectly fine. Guess that i have to work with it like that until there is a solution to my rendering problem.

Comment: I can only run it on my phone when i created it in default, whereas if i start editing it, error all over again and i can't run it on my phone.